# Anaconda Downloading full package

Tags: python, anaconda

I know I can use: conda install package-name to download a package and it will also download any dependencies needed.

The problem is that I want to install a package on a stand alone pc.
Is there a way, On another pc with internet, to ask conda to download the package and all dependencies without really install it so I can copy it to the stend alone pc?

Comment: Does this help? https://deparkes.co.uk/2015/02/04/anaconda-whl-install/

Comment: Thanks But no. Its about instelling whl file that you download. I want the conda to do the whole download for me and save it for later use.

Comment: depending on the problem you are trying to solve this may be an option: https://github.com/conda/constructor